# Return value from array where greater than 0 in array below

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkTLV.png)

In A2, find in Row 2 where the value is >0, then return the Value above in Row 1.

I could write an endless IF statement, but I have many columns to search through. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **A2** enter:

```
=INDEX(B1:Z1,MATCH(TRUE,B2:Z2>0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. INDEX/MATCH ftw once again. I did not realize you can attach a greater than to an array to check every cell. Cheers